# Is it possible to find which network interface client is connected to with PHP?

Tags: php, bash, shell, network-programming, freebsd

I want to find which network interface client connected on. Is it possible?

If it is possible with Bash or another scripting language. It is acceptable for me.

I am working on Freebsd.

Here is how code should look like.

```
function get_connected_interface(){
//...
}
echo get_connected_interface(); //should print network interface. for example em0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache, PHP is setting $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] to be the **destination** ip address where the client connected to te server.

If you are using nginx, lighttpd or other webserver, look at the result of a page with only `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to know how to get the **ip address** of the **destination** (one of the ip addresses of your server)

In any case, you could use this PHP script to launch `ifconfig` and search for the interface having this ip address.

I'd say that :

```
function get_connected_interface() {
  static $interfaces=array();
  if (!count($interfaces)) {
    $curif="";
    // launch ifconfig and parse its result (inet/inet6)
    // but only at first function call
    exec("ifconfig",$out);
    foreach($out as $line) {
      if (preg_match("#^([a-z0-9\.]*): #",$line,$mat)) {
    $curif=$mat[1];
      }
      if (preg_match("#inet ([0-9\.]*) #",$line,$mat)) {
    $interfaces[$mat[1]]=$curif;
      }
      if (preg_match("#inet6 ([0-9a-fA-F:]*) #",$line,$mat)) {
    $interfaces[$mat[1]]=$curif;
      }
    }
  }
  return $interfaces[$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]];
}
```